# In HTML and CSS, what is the best way to deal with SVG anchor links and change SVG color when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using SVG logo that will be used as anchor links. By default, the SVG are black and I wanted them to be a shade of purple, so i add `fill="#7b0aa8` in the SVG file on VS Code.
But I can't make the SVG change to a specific color with mouse hover.
If I use filter generated with [codepen sosuke](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp), the filter will change the color based on the current color(In this case, purple), but the code is made to change base on black, so I can't use the filter properly.
Is there a better way to deal with SVG anchor links so I can change the color in CSS precisely?

```html
<header class="header">

  <a class="header__link" target="blank" href="#">
    <img class="icone" src="./assets/icons/iconmonstr-github-1.svg"    alt="Logo GitHub">
  </a>
 
  <a class="header__link" target="blank" href="#">
    <img class="icone" src="./assets/icons/iconmonstr-linkedin-3.svg" alt="Logo LikedIn">
  </a>
 
  <a class="header__link" target="blank" href="#">
    <img class="icone" src="./assets/icons/itchio-textless-black.svg" alt="">
  </a>       
</header>
```

Comment: what are your logos?

Comment: https://iconmonstr.com/linkedin-3-svg/ for LinkedIn ///
https://iconmonstr.com/github-1-svg/ for GitHub ///
https://static.itch.io/images/itchio-textless-black.svg for Itch.Io

Comment: they are all based on a black color, so what is the problem?

Comment: Did you read my answer there ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters/56723735#56723735

Comment: It seems a litte bit advanced for me right now, but I will give it a try, thx

Comment: See also ["How to access style properties of externally insert svg file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70811533/how-to-access-style-properties-of-externally-insert-svg-file/70816672#70816672). You can use `<use>` elements with external file references. However you should remove predefined fill colors from icon `<path>` elements to facilitate styling (or set `currentColor` to inherit text colors).

Answer (score 0):

If you include the svg as code then you should be able to just use the hover event on the path. In this example it works better if you use the parent anchor to control the hover. Notice the second example hover only works in actual fill areas.

```css
     a > .svgstyle path{
       fill: green; 
    }

     a:hover .svgstyle path {
    fill: purple; 
    }

    .svgstyle2 path {
    fill:green;
    }
    .svgstyle2 path:hover {
    fill: purple;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#"><svg class="svgstyle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="235.452" width="261.728" viewBox="0 0 245.371 220.736"><path d="M31.99 1.365C21.287 7.72.2 31.945 0 38.298v10.516C0 62.144 12.46 73.86 23.773 73.86c13.584 0 24.902-11.258 24.903-24.62 0 13.362 10.93 24.62 24.515 24.62 13.586 0 24.165-11.258 24.165-24.62 0 13.362 11.622 24.62 25.207 24.62h.246c13.586 0 25.208-11.258 25.208-24.62 0 13.362 10.58 24.62 24.164 24.62 13.585 0 24.515-11.258 24.515-24.62 0 13.362 11.32 24.62 24.903 24.62 11.313 0 23.773-11.714 23.773-25.046V38.298c-.2-6.354-21.287-30.58-31.988-36.933C180.118.197 157.056-.005 122.685 0c-34.37.003-81.228.54-90.697 1.365zm65.194 66.217a28.025 28.025 0 0 1-4.78 6.155c-5.128 5.014-12.157 8.122-19.906 8.122a28.482 28.482 0 0 1-19.948-8.126c-1.858-1.82-3.27-3.766-4.563-6.032l-.006.004c-1.292 2.27-3.092 4.215-4.954 6.037a28.5 28.5 0 0 1-19.948 8.12c-.934 0-1.906-.258-2.692-.528-1.092 11.372-1.553 22.24-1.716 30.164l-.002.045c-.02 4.024-.04 7.333-.06 11.93.21 23.86-2.363 77.334 10.52 90.473 19.964 4.655 56.7 6.775 93.555 6.788h.006c36.854-.013 73.59-2.133 93.554-6.788 12.883-13.14 10.31-66.614 10.52-90.474-.022-4.596-.04-7.905-.06-11.93l-.003-.045c-.162-7.926-.623-18.793-1.715-30.165-.786.27-1.757.528-2.692.528a28.5 28.5 0 0 1-19.948-8.12c-1.862-1.822-3.662-3.766-4.955-6.037l-.006-.004c-1.294 2.266-2.705 4.213-4.563 6.032a28.48 28.48 0 0 1-19.947 8.125c-7.748 0-14.778-3.11-19.906-8.123a28.025 28.025 0 0 1-4.78-6.155 27.99 27.99 0 0 1-4.736 6.155 28.49 28.49 0 0 1-19.95 8.124c-.27 0-.54-.012-.81-.02h-.007c-.27.008-.54.02-.813.02a28.49 28.49 0 0 1-19.95-8.123 27.992 27.992 0 0 1-4.736-6.155zm-20.486 26.49l-.002.01h.015c8.113.017 15.32 0 24.25 9.746 7.028-.737 14.372-1.105 21.722-1.094h.006c7.35-.01 14.694.357 21.723 1.094 8.93-9.747 16.137-9.73 24.25-9.746h.014l-.002-.01c3.833 0 19.166 0 29.85 30.007L210 165.244c8.504 30.624-2.723 31.373-16.727 31.4-20.768-.773-32.267-15.855-32.267-30.935-11.496 1.884-24.907 2.826-38.318 2.827h-.006c-13.412 0-26.823-.943-38.318-2.827 0 15.08-11.5 30.162-32.267 30.935-14.004-.027-25.23-.775-16.726-31.4L46.85 124.08C57.534 94.073 72.867 94.073 76.7 94.073zm45.985 23.582v.006c-.02.02-21.863 20.08-25.79 27.215l14.304-.573v12.474c0 .584 5.74.346 11.486.08h.006c5.744.266 11.485.504 11.485-.08v-12.474l14.304.573c-3.928-7.135-25.79-27.215-25.79-27.215v-.006l-.003.002z" color="#000"/></svg>     </a>




    <a href="#"><svg class="svgstyle2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="235.452" width="261.728" viewBox="0 0 245.371 220.736"><path d="M31.99 1.365C21.287 7.72.2 31.945 0 38.298v10.516C0 62.144 12.46 73.86 23.773 73.86c13.584 0 24.902-11.258 24.903-24.62 0 13.362 10.93 24.62 24.515 24.62 13.586 0 24.165-11.258 24.165-24.62 0 13.362 11.622 24.62 25.207 24.62h.246c13.586 0 25.208-11.258 25.208-24.62 0 13.362 10.58 24.62 24.164 24.62 13.585 0 24.515-11.258 24.515-24.62 0 13.362 11.32 24.62 24.903 24.62 11.313 0 23.773-11.714 23.773-25.046V38.298c-.2-6.354-21.287-30.58-31.988-36.933C180.118.197 157.056-.005 122.685 0c-34.37.003-81.228.54-90.697 1.365zm65.194 66.217a28.025 28.025 0 0 1-4.78 6.155c-5.128 5.014-12.157 8.122-19.906 8.122a28.482 28.482 0 0 1-19.948-8.126c-1.858-1.82-3.27-3.766-4.563-6.032l-.006.004c-1.292 2.27-3.092 4.215-4.954 6.037a28.5 28.5 0 0 1-19.948 8.12c-.934 0-1.906-.258-2.692-.528-1.092 11.372-1.553 22.24-1.716 30.164l-.002.045c-.02 4.024-.04 7.333-.06 11.93.21 23.86-2.363 77.334 10.52 90.473 19.964 4.655 56.7 6.775 93.555 6.788h.006c36.854-.013 73.59-2.133 93.554-6.788 12.883-13.14 10.31-66.614 10.52-90.474-.022-4.596-.04-7.905-.06-11.93l-.003-.045c-.162-7.926-.623-18.793-1.715-30.165-.786.27-1.757.528-2.692.528a28.5 28.5 0 0 1-19.948-8.12c-1.862-1.822-3.662-3.766-4.955-6.037l-.006-.004c-1.294 2.266-2.705 4.213-4.563 6.032a28.48 28.48 0 0 1-19.947 8.125c-7.748 0-14.778-3.11-19.906-8.123a28.025 28.025 0 0 1-4.78-6.155 27.99 27.99 0 0 1-4.736 6.155 28.49 28.49 0 0 1-19.95 8.124c-.27 0-.54-.012-.81-.02h-.007c-.27.008-.54.02-.813.02a28.49 28.49 0 0 1-19.95-8.123 27.992 27.992 0 0 1-4.736-6.155zm-20.486 26.49l-.002.01h.015c8.113.017 15.32 0 24.25 9.746 7.028-.737 14.372-1.105 21.722-1.094h.006c7.35-.01 14.694.357 21.723 1.094 8.93-9.747 16.137-9.73 24.25-9.746h.014l-.002-.01c3.833 0 19.166 0 29.85 30.007L210 165.244c8.504 30.624-2.723 31.373-16.727 31.4-20.768-.773-32.267-15.855-32.267-30.935-11.496 1.884-24.907 2.826-38.318 2.827h-.006c-13.412 0-26.823-.943-38.318-2.827 0 15.08-11.5 30.162-32.267 30.935-14.004-.027-25.23-.775-16.726-31.4L46.85 124.08C57.534 94.073 72.867 94.073 76.7 94.073zm45.985 23.582v.006c-.02.02-21.863 20.08-25.79 27.215l14.304-.573v12.474c0 .584 5.74.346 11.486.08h.006c5.744.266 11.485.504 11.485-.08v-12.474l14.304.573c-3.928-7.135-25.79-27.215-25.79-27.215v-.006l-.003.002z" color="#000"/></svg>     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you use it as code, with `fill="currentColor"` in the svg code. Then you can use CSS to use the normal `color` property

Comment: Thx, it worked, but just as code. I guess this is the best way to use SVG. At least for this usage